# RDFLib Blank Node Printing

Tags: python, rdf, rdflib, blank-nodes

I have an RDF dataset where triples are stored in N-Triples format like follows:

```
<http://ebola.ndssl.bi.vt.edu/country/1> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://ebola.ndssl.bi.vt.edu/vocab/country> .
_:AmapX3aXcountryX5fXcountryX5fXnameX5fXclassMapX40XX40X1 <http://ebola.ndssl.bi.vt.edu/vocab/hasValue> "Guinea" .
```

I want to do some processing with the blank nodes. I am writing a program to reading this file in Python. I am using Python RDFLib library. After reading the file, I print its content. However, the problem is blank node name is coming out differently. For example:

```
_:AmapX3aXcountryX5fXcountryX5fXnameX5fXclassMapX40XX40X1
 is showing like following
N75424221e7df43708c3e2a135e3e888b
```

I need original RDF file blank node name as follows:

```
_:AmapX3aXcountryX5fXcountryX5fXnameX5fXclassMapX40XX40X1
```

How can I print original RDF file blank node name?

Answer (score 5):

You (probably) can't. Blank node ids are local to the specific file they are in, they're not guaranteed preserved between different serializations. RDFLib simply replaces the id with its own new internal id.

Some tools have a parser setting to optionally preserve node ids. I don't know if RDFLib supports this, but even if it does: unless you have a *very* specific use case you should not be relying on blank node ids being preserved. They are called *blank* for a reason: their id is for all intents and purposes "unknown".

Comment: Could you please give me the name of such tool?

Comment: RDF4J's Rio parser supports this, for one. I'm pretty sure Jena's Riot parser does, too. I don't know whether RDFLib supports it or not, it might (have a look in the parser documentation). But as said: in most cases you _really_ shouldn't rely on this.

Comment: Better still, if you need to rely on those being considered the same resource, give them an IRI and use that.

Comment: @S.M.ShamimulHasan Yes, Michael's suggestion to use an IRI is the best one here.  And you don't have to use http IRIs, either.  You can use things like `urn:ex:AmapX3aXcountryX5fXcountryX5fXnameX5fXclassMapX40XX40X1` which would still let you reliably recognize which ones are your "special" IRIs.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, please can you give me more details how can i do that.it is big problem i faced in my phd project now.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra please can you give me a reference on example in RDF4J?

Comment: @bib See the RDF4J documentation, specifically http://docs.rdf4j.org/programming/#_configuring_the_parser

Comment: Jena can do it (see RDFParser.create().labelToNode(...)) but like @JeenBroekstra says, if preserving blank node labels matters, maybe there is a wider issue.  Use URIs, maybe convert to URIs, process and reverse the process (if needed for backwards compatibility) - this is called skolemization