# how to preserve the same name for blank node after serialization?

Tags: rdf, jena, owl, rdflib, blank-nodes

I have a RDF graph including blank nodes. What is the best library to use which preserve the same name for the blank nodes after serialization as there are given in the RDF file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RDFLib Blank Node Printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38962190/rdflib-blank-node-printing)

Comment: Blank node ids are not preserved by design - they're local to the serialization. What is the requirement that needs satisfying?